# Explanation of this SQL code in adding PRIMARY KEY index

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw the following SQL code. I perfectly understand it. But what am not getting is what the **66** in the code does.

```
CREATE TABLE `wordpress`.`campaign_queue` ( 
      `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (`id`(66))
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation of the query: it is telling MySQL to create a **sub part key*** on the first 66 letters of **id** column. This only works for string types, so that query will return an error unless you change the field type to **String**

Comment: Can you please give me a link that explains how sub part key works?

Comment: explain your explanation pliz

Answer (score 1):

This give you error:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_queue1` ( 
      `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (`id`(66))
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

because the `(66)` is to set string length.

> Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys

If you change the type to `VARCHAR` then the problem would be with the `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_queue2` ( 
      `id` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`(10))
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

> Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'

Comment: Ignore the error. I just want to know what the **10** in your last code block does.

Comment: in the second example, if you remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` that reduce the length of the string to `10` instead of `100` For example if you have a string with `'1234567890  2017-03-21'` the key will be only the first 10 characters

Comment: Of what importance then is doing that if we can specify the limit as `VARCHAR(10)`

Comment: Because the Key will be shorter to compare and validate. Also the index for the PK will by smaller. Imagine you have a product code with `product_id - manufacture_id - expire_date - brand_id` the code is long but for the key you only need the first code. Of course you could have a separated field just for `product_id`

Comment: Thank you your explanation.